# Reading from buffer versus calculating on the fly performance

Tags: compute-shader, hlsl, optimisation

I am creating a fast fourier transform algorithm for the compute shader - i am no expert on how GPUs really run optimally so thought i would ask here.

I have the option to calculate on the fly or precompute a lot of the trig function (cos and sin) values and store it in a read only float buffer.

My question is, though i am aware cos() and sin() is fast, how do they compare to simply getting the value precomputed in a buffer instead?

I don't mean a LUT here i do not need to interpolate between values from the buffer so i just get them values directly. I don't know how to really bench test shaders properly so i am unsure which is faster.

Perhaps some one knows more info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, though i am aware cos() and sin() is fast, how do they compare to simply getting the value precomputed in a buffer instead?

This will depend on your shader code and GPU model.

- GPUs utilize latency hiding by executing independent ALU instructions while waiting for data to arrive from memory.
- Accessing memory is usually the slowest operation on a GPU.

If your shader code allows for latency hiding, it *may* be faster.

The best option here is to profile the shader performance.

> I don't know how to really bench test shaders properly so i am unsure which is faster.

I think the easiest way would be to download [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/) and get a frame capture of your application.

After that, you click on the timing icon (shown red) to get some measurements.

[image]

Although these are not super accurate measurements, they're good enough and sort of representative of the application performance.

For precise measurements, you'll need your GPU vendor's graphics profiling tools.

- AMD has [Radeon Graphics Profiler (RGP)](https://gpuopen.com/rgp/)
- NVIDIA has [NSight](https://developer.nvidia.com/tools-overview)
- INTEL has [Graphics Performance Analyzers](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/graphics-performance-analyzers.html)

---

**Update**: Below are some captures from RGP, showing GPU assembly instructions and instruction timings of various instruction types. You can see latency hiding in action below:

- `vmem` : texture read
- `smem` : constant buffer / descriptor<texture/buffer> read
- `ALU`  : math ops (arithmetic / logic)
- `sync` : waits for vmem/smem instructions to finish loading data from memory

[image]

Another capture showing instruction timings while first two texture loads not having latency hiding.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow accessing memory is the slowest? Did not know that. That seems likely then the trig functions are probably going to win out here. Thanks for the advice on profiling! I will look into it!

Comment: @wduk GPU memory is many more times slower than a CPU memory (to access) due to higher latency. However, once the data starts streaming, the bandwidth is much larger than a CPU's mem bandwidth. I've updated the answer and added some screen captures demonstrating latency hiding!